# SQL Server localdb RESTORE runs forever?

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio, restore

I'm using visual Studio 2019 community SQL Server localdb on Windows 10 Pro 202H. I've  been trying 'restore' the WideWorldImporters database from WideWorldImporters-Full.bak (downloaded from GitHub)  to my localdb instances without any success.

This has happened so far:
Qyery:  (*** = My Username)

```sql
 USE master 
 RESTORE DATABASE WideWorldImporters 
 FROM disk = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\WideWorldImporters-Full.bak' 
 WITH MOVE 'WWI_Primary' TO 'C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB\WideWorldImporters.mdf', 
 MOVE 'WWI_UserData' TO 'C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB\WideWorldImporters_UserData.ndf', 
 MOVE 'WWI_Log' TO 'C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB\WideWorldImporters.ldf', 
 MOVE 'WWI_InMemory_Data_1' TO 'C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB\WideWorldImporters_InMemory_Data_1', 
 REPLACE
```

Message (pane) :

```
Processed 1464 pages for database 'WideWorldImporters', file 'WWI_Primary' on file 1.
Processed 53096 pages for database 'WideWorldImporters', file 'WWI_UserData' on file 1.
Processed 33 pages for database 'WideWorldImporters', file 'WWI_Log' on file 1.
Processed 3862 pages for database 'WideWorldImporters', file 'WWI_InMemory_Data_1' on file 1.

100% | No issues found
Executing query... (is running on and on) 

Output (General)  is empty

All the stuff notified in message window can be found in desitination folder:
WideWorldImportes_UserData.ndf                    (2 097 152 kb) 
WideWorldImportes.mdf                             (1 048 576 kb) 
WideWorldImportes.ldf                             (  102 400 kb) 

\WideWorldImportes_InMemory_Data_1\
filestream.hdr                                    (        1 kb) 

 \$FSLOG                                          (empty       ) 

 \$HKv2
{1E6DC7E6-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}.hkckp      (    2 048 kb)      
{3E231B6B-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}.hkckp      (       20 kb) 
{4B9D83BE-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}.hkckp      (    2 048 kb) 
{6E82296C-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}.hkckp      (   16 384 kb) 
{6F44D507-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}.hkckp      (    1 024 kb) 
{07FEB052-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}.hkckp      (       20 kb) 
{7C4940C1-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}.hkckp      (    1 024 kb) 
{9A77966E-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}.hkckp      (    4 096 kb) 
{28CE0994-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}.hkckp      (   16 384 kb) 
{63F1F945-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}.hkckp      (    2 048 kb) 
{79B6C099-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}.hkckp      (    4 096 kb) 
{122A2C90-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}.hkckp      (   16 384 kb) 
{285FCA71-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}.hkckp      (        4 kb) 
{421C57F0-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}.hkckp      (    4 096 kb) 
{A54BA375-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}.hkckp      (    1 024 kb) 
{C818BEE6-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}.hkckp      (   30 836 kb) 
{CB6FF974-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}.hkckp      (    1 024 kb) 
{F6F88B52-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}.hkckp      (    1 024 kb) 
{F756E9B8-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}.hkckp      (    1 024 kb)
```

Executing query... (still running, no changes in size of files for the last two hours)

This is where I'm now
[image: the dialog]

and I'm getting mad
[image: the object browser]

Comment: You could install [WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com/) and look for any blocking processes.

Comment: Have you checked for things like drive space, tempDB space, Log file growth. Check SqlServer error log.

Comment: `select * from sys.dm_exec_requests` should give you lots of info, in particular the `blocking_session_id, wait_resource, percent_complete` columns

Comment: That's not a query, that's a RESTORE operation. `LocalDB` is an *embedded* database so it's slow by definition. The screenshot shows that restoring has finished, and the server is processing interrupted transactions (which suggests the backup was taken at a busy time). Why don't you use SQL Server Express?You've already installed it after all - LocalDB is a feature of SQL Server Express

Comment: Or you could use SQL Server Developer, which is *also* free but has the full Enterprise feature set like parallelism by default and online restores.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I installed the Express edition as a named instance and finally got it to work, though it wasn't easy. I'll tell you and everyone all the rest later how to do the trick by answering to my own question because this has not got room enough.

Answer (score 1):

As you have gone for the option of `RESTORE WITH REPLACE`, it has overwritten existing WideWorldImporters database. As you have done restore with replace option, there could be uncommitted transactions, which it is trying to clean up. It will come back online after some time.

You have to be careful with REPLACE option. [From MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> #### REPLACE Option Impact
>
> REPLACE should be used rarely and only after
> careful consideration. Restore normally prevents accidentally
> overwriting a database with a different database. If the database
> specified in a RESTORE statement already exists on the current server
> and the specified database family GUID differs from the database
> family GUID recorded in the backup set, the database is not restored.
> This is an important safeguard.
>
> The REPLACE option overrides several important safety checks that
> restore normally performs. The overridden checks are as follows:
>
> - Restoring over an existing database with a backup taken of another
>   database.
>
> With the REPLACE option, restore allows you to overwrite an existing
> database with whatever database is in the backup set, even if the
> specified database name differs from the database name recorded in the
> backup set. This can result in accidentally overwriting a database by
> a different database.
>
> - Restoring over a database using the full or bulk-logged recovery model
>   where a tail-log backup has not been taken and the STOPAT option is
>   not used.
>
> With the REPLACE option, you can lose committed work, because the log
> written most recently has not been backed up.
>
> - Overwriting existing files.
>
> For example, a mistake could allow overwriting files of the wrong
> type, such as .xls files, or that are being used by another database
> that is not online. Arbitrary data loss is possible if existing files
> are overwritten, although the restored database is complete.

You can read, how to come out of the restoring mode here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5460/sql-server-database-stuck-in-restoring-state/